# Executing Premetheus Middleware on /metrics path only in asp.net core App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, prometheus

From the documentation of Prometheus, I implemented a middleware in order to create metrics. Prometheus out puts text file of these metrics by default in /metrics end point ... it works perfectly fine but the problem is that that middleware get called for each and every page hit which make app super slow...

how can I make that middleware to be called only when user request for /metrics ?
Im sorry if question is not that clear because this is my first experience with Prometheus on asp.net core app

I used Prometheus-net.AspNetCore library

MetricsMiddleware.cs

```
public class MetricsMiddleware
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MetricsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this._next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
               await _next.Invoke(httpContext);

            //custome metrics created here
        }

        public static class MetricsMiddlewareExtensions
        {
          public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequestMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
          {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestMiddleware>();
          }
        }
}
```

stratup.cs file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ....)

{

app.UseMetricServer();            
app.UseMetricsMiddleware();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map function to apply a middleware to specifc route. Like code below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{           
    app.Map("/metrics", innerApp =>
    {
        innerApp.UseMetricsMiddleware());
        innerApp.UseMetricServer();
    }
}
```